# Flatten JSON List to Nested Structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of flatten json objects. I want to parse and form a nested json structure.

Below is the list of flattened JSON objects:

```
     [
      {
        "seId" : "35EB8012",
        "snumber" : 1,
        "department" : 1,
        "jId" : "1",
        "width": 576,
        "depth": 18,
        "height": 78
     },
     {
        "seId" : "35EB8012",
        "snumber" : 1,
        "department" : 1,
        "jId" : "1",
        "width": 132,
        "depth": 18,
        "height": 60
      },
      {
       "seId" : "45EA8012",
       "snumber" : 2,
       "department" : 2,
       "jId" : "1",
       "width": 132,
       "depth": 18,
       "height": 60
      }
    ]
```

I want to form a nested json structure.

```
  { "stats" : [ {
    "seId" : "35EB8012",
    "jobOutPut" : [
    {
            "jId" : "1",
           [ {
            "snumber" : 1,
            "deparment" : 1,
            "placement" : [{
                "width" : 576,
                "depth" : 18,
                "height" : 78
            },{
                "width" : 132,
                "depth" : 80,
                "height" : 60
            }
             }
            ],

            }
        }
    }
      ]
     }, {
         "seId" : "45EA8012",
          "jobOutPut" : [
         {
            "jId" : "20",
            {
            "snumber" : 2,
            "deparment" : 2,
            "placement" : [{
                "width" : 132,
                "depth" : 80,
                "height" : 60}
            ]
           }
          }
         }
         ]
        }
      ]
      }
```

I tried pandas group by but not able to form the inner lists. Here I tried grouping the list based on seid. But I am not getting the inner list.

```
   stats = pd.DataFrame(arraylist)
   stats_df = strategy_result.groupby(by=['seId']).agg(list)
```

I need to group on 3 fields (seId), (jId), (snumber, department)

Comment: Not sure dict after `"jId"`, is it correct?

Comment: @jezrael for every jId I need to group documents. And for every document I need to group height width dept based on snumber, department

Comment: There missing keys for it, so add in answer `new`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(arraylist)

f = lambda x: x.to_dict('records')
df = df.groupby(['seId','snumber','department','jId'])[['width','depth','height']].apply(f).reset_index(name='placement')
df = df.groupby(['seId','jId'])[['snumber','department','placement']].apply(f).reset_index(name='new')
df = df.groupby('seId')[['jId','new']].apply(f).reset_index(name='jobOutPut')

d = json.dumps({"stats" : df.to_dict('records')})
```

Comment: This solution worked. I was looking for this only . I understood the logic. 
I added another level of grouping and it is working