# Flatten JSON List to Nested Structure Using Pandas Group By

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my Previous Question: - [Flatten JSON List to Nested Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997395/flatten-json-list-to-nested-structure?noredirect=1#comment120185179_67997395)

Form previous solution I want to change the placemcnt type list to simple dictionary. This is sample input list flatten structure

```
 [
    {
    "seId" : "35EB8012",
    "snumber" : 1,
    "department" : 1,
    "jId" : "1",
    "width": 576,
    "depth": 18,
    "height": 78
 }
]
```

I want to form a nested json structure.

```
 {
"stats": [{
    "seId": "35EB8012",
    "jobOutPut": [{
        "jId": "1",
        "new": [{
            "snumber": 1,
            "deparment": 1,
            "placement": {
                "width": 576,
                "depth": 18,
                "height": 78
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Here I want to change the placement list type to dict.
**{'width','depth','height'}**

```
    import json
    df = pd.DataFrame(arraylist)

    f = lambda x: x.to_dict('records')
    df = df.groupby(['seId','snumber','department','jId'])[{'width','depth','height'}].apply(f).reset_index(name='placement')
    df = df.groupby(['seId','jId'])[['snumber','department','placement']].apply(f).reset_index(name='new')
    df = df.groupby('seId')[['jId','new']].apply(f).reset_index(name='jobOutPut')

    d = json.dumps({"stats" : df.to_dict('records')})
```

Any Suggestion How Can I do it using pandas and using group by.

Comment: Why do you need pandas here? I took a look at the previous question. It is answered there. Please try to do it on your own.

Comment: @Vishnudev I tried multiple times. I know it will be a very small change . But I am new to pandas and python. 
Posting question is the final step for many when we dont get expected solution after trying multiple times

Comment: When you did not get an answer after trying multiple times, please post the attempt and establish your effort.

Comment: The "nested" JSON you give in the example isn't a valid JSON. It's unclear what structure you're trying to achieve. Please groom it and make it readable with https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer. Also please explain, why do you need pandas and not vanilla python?

Comment: @gukoff Updated the JSON structure. Regarding vanilla python my project doesnt want to add new dependenciee so trying out with existing pandas

Comment: I mean plain python :) You don't need pandas or any other library to do it. Python has all the tools for it already.

Comment: @gukoff I am new to python. I didnt used any tools but i solved this by iterating it multiple times used data structures list, dict. 
It will be helpful if you name a few tools